# ошибка, связанная с gets() c++

Tags: c++

решаю задачу на coderbyte, там массив читается так:

```
int main() { 
  int A[] = gets(stdin);
  cout << ArrayAdditionI(A, sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A));
  return 0;
}
```

И компилятор на сайте не придирается, но в ide выдает ошибку:

> no matching function for call to 'gets'

Так же за ошибку считает: sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A)

> invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'int []'

Вопрос в том, откуда возникает эта ошибка, и как ее исправить.

Comment: В языке С++ никакого `int A[] = gets(stdin);` нет и быть не может. То есть написана полная бессмыслица. Вот, собственно и все. Более того, стандартной функции `gets` в С и С++ больше нет. (И даже когда она существовала, поток в качестве входного параметра она никогда не принимала.) А уж что за `gets` имеется в виду в вашем примере - это уже у вас нужно спрашивать. Вы привели какой-то огрызок кода. Как его "исправлять"?

Comment: `gets(stdin)` - неправильная запись. Откуда вы такое взяли? Неужели [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269252/what-is-going-on-with-getsstdin-on-the-site-coderbyte)?

Comment: Взяла с сайта coderbyte. Спасибо, теперь понятно, почему это не работает у меня в ide.

Comment: @freim: А где вы увидели "размер указателя"? Если `A` - массив, то `*A` - это `A[0]`, т.е. элемент массива. Никаких указателей.

Comment: @AnT, верно, что-то не туда я поехал. Удаляю свой комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

`gets(stdin)` - это какое-то извращение, специфичное для сайта CoderByte. Подробности [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269252/what-is-going-on-with-getsstdin-on-the-site-coderbyte).

CoderByte перед компиляцией прямо в коде ищет запись `gets(stdin)`, заменяет ее на список чисел `{a, b, c...}`, и передает компилятору уже измененный код.

В стандартном С++ эта функция работает по-другому. (А начиная с С++14 ее больше нет в языке.)